# How to give border on kendo grid row hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I created a grid with Kendo and I want to show the border when my cursor is on a grid row (hovering).

I tried this:

```
.k-grid > table > tbody > tr:hover,
.k-grid-content > table > tbody > tr:hover
{
   background-color: transparent;
   border:1px solid #000
}
```

but it didn't work for me. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D What i can add sorry?? I have grid with kendo and i want to show border on hover. What i can add more tell me i can add.I can add my grid code also but it's not need this is css problem

Comment: What about td's background, is there any?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus no i want to give border all "tr" on hover.

Comment: Can we reproduce it with the code you have provided? No...so we need a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `outline` on `tr:hover` and play with content and header to match it up.

```
.k-grid tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    outline: #4CAF50 solid 2px;
}

.k-grid-content {
    padding: 1px;
}

.k-grid-header-wrap {
    padding: 1px;
}
```

For example: [Grid tr outline](https://dojo.telerik.com/oXiyUPEx)